# React Styled Component doesn't show correct output

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

I've changed my style in StyledButton tag but it doesn't reflect on webpage. Can you help what is wrong in this code

```
   import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import './App.css';
    //import Radium, {StyleRoot} from 'radium';
    import Person from './Person/Person';
    import { render } from 'react-dom';
    import styled from 'styled-components'

const StyledButton = styled.button `
background-color:  ${props => props.alt ? 'red' : 'green'};   //Here I have define these property which is not reflecting in output
color: white;
font: inherit;
border: 1px solid blue;
padding: 8px;
cursor:pointer;
&:hover:{
  background-color:${props => props.alt ? 'salmon' : 'green'}; //Hover Function is also not working
  color:black;
}`;

class App extends Component {
state ={
  persons : [
{id:'12', name: 'Max', age: 28},
{id:'21', name: 'Manu', age:29},
{id:'33', name: 'Nikhil', age:23}
]};
nameChangeHandler = (event, id) => {
  const personIndex = this.state.persons.findIndex(p=>{
    return p.id===id;
  });

  const person = {
    ... this.state.persons[personIndex]
  };

  person.name = event.target.value;
  const persons =[...this.state.persons];
  persons[personIndex]=person;

  this.setState({ persons: persons
});
}

deletePersonHandler = (personIndex) =>{
  //const persons = this.state.persons.slice();
  //const persons = this.state.persons
  const persons = [... this.state.persons];
  persons.splice(personIndex,1);
  this.setState({persons: persons})
}

togglePersonsHandler = ()=> {
  const doesShow = this.state.showPersons;
  this.setState({showPersons: !doesShow});
}

render()
{
  let persons = null;
    if(this.state.showPersons)
      {
      persons = (
        <div>
        { this.state.persons.map((person, index) =>{
          return <Person
           click = { () => this.deletePersonHandler(index) }
           name={person.name}
           age={person.age}
           key= {person.id}
           changed={(event)=> this.nameChangeHandler(event, person.id)}/>
        })}
    </div>
    );
    //StyledButton.backgroundColor= 'red';

      }

let classes = []
if(this.state.persons.length<=2)
{
  classes.push('red');
}
if(this.state.persons.length<=1)
{
  classes.push('bold');
}

  return (

    <div className = "App">
      <h1>Hi there this is my first react application</h1>
      <p className= {classes.join(' ')}>Hi this is really working</p>
      <StyledButton
       alt ={ this.state.showPersons }
       onClick = {this.togglePersonsHandler}>Toggle Persons</StyledButton>
       { persons }


    </div>


  );

}
}

export default App;
```

Code just toggle the names and ages when user click on button and delete the names when click on the paragraph and adding certain classes these are all works fine.

I'm using styled component package on toggle button and it is not working properly, I don't why Please let me know if you understand

Comment: What version of `styled-components` are you using? Is it just the background color that isn't working as expected?

Comment: You're checking `props.$alt` but the property you're passing is `alt`...

Comment: @DrewReese Yes background color isn't working when { this.state.showPersons } is true or False

Comment: and I'm using 5.2.3 latest version of  `styled-components`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've defined `alt` to be a [transient prop](https://styled-components.com/docs/api#transient-props), i.e. `$alt`, but you don't pass that prop to the `StyledButton`.

You've also a typo in your hover selector, there's a trailing colon (`:`): `&:hover:` should be `:hover` (*the leading parent node selector `&` is also unnecessary*).

```
const StyledButton = styled.button `
  background-color: ${props => props.$alt ? 'red' : 'green'};
  color: white;
  font: inherit;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  padding: 8px;
  cursor: pointer;
  :hover {
    background-color:${props => props.$alt ? 'salmon' : 'green'}; 
    color:black;
  }
`;

...

<StyledButton
  $alt={this.state.showPersons} // <-- pass transient prop
  onClick={this.togglePersonsHandler}
>
  Toggle Persons
</StyledButton>
```

This was introduced in v5.1. If you didn't intend to declare a transient prop or you aren't on v5.1 or newer, then simply remove the `$` and use the `alt` prop.

```
const StyledButton = styled.button `
  background-color: ${props => props.alt ? 'red' : 'green'};
  color: white;
  font: inherit;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  padding: 8px;
  cursor: pointer;
  :hover {
    background-color:${props => props.alt ? 'salmon' : 'green'}; 
    color:black;
  }
}`;

...

<StyledButton
  alt={this.state.showPersons} // <-- use alt prop
  onClick={this.togglePersonsHandler}
>
  Toggle Persons
</StyledButton>
```

## Demo

[image: Edit react-styled-component-doesnt-show-correct-output/]

Comment: They just edited their question... which seems to imply that's not the issue?

Comment: using alt still I'm not seeing any changes btw thanks for the details you've given.

Comment: @NikhilKarnwal You also had a trailing colon on the hover pseudoselector. Please check updated answer.